# This is driving me crazy - Line 42:40: 'firebase' is not defined no-undef

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I'm having trouble figuring out what is wrong with my code. I am still learning react so please bear with me :) This is coming from a tutorial I am following, and while they have no issue, for some reason my code is not compiling. Driving me nuts for 8 hours already! please scroll down to where ** ** is thanks guys!!

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import { storage, db } from "./firebase";

function ImageUpload({username}) {
    const [image, setImage] = useState('null');
    const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
    const [caption, setCaption] = useState('');

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        if (e.target.files[0]) {
            setImage(e.target.files[0]);
        }
    };

    const handleUpload = () => {
        const uploadTask = storage.ref(`images/${image.name}`).put(image);

        uploadTask.on(
            "state_changed",
            (snapshot) => {
                // progress function...
                const progress = Math.round(
                (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
                );
                setProgress(progress);
            },
            (error) => {
                // error function...
                console.log(error);
                alert(error.message);
            },
            () => {
                // complete function...
                storage
                    .ref("images")
                    .child(image.name)
                    .getDownloadURL()
                    .then(url => {
                        // post image inside db
                        db.collection("posts").add({
                            **timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),**
                            caption: caption,
                            imageUrl: url,
                            username: username,
                        })

                    })
            }
        )
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>abc</h1>

            <input type="text" placeholder='Enter a caption...' onChange={event => setCaption(event.target.value)} value={caption}/>
            <input type="file" onChange={handleChange} />
            <Button onClick={handleUpload}>
                Upload
            </Button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ImageUpload
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're doing the same tutorial. Video timestamp at 2:37:30 somehow magically the import statement appears up at the top

```
import firebase from "firebase";
```

Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that you don't have an import for `firebase`.  JavaScript just doesn't know what `firebase` is in this files since there's no import or other declaration.

```
timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
```

It looks like you have an import that finds other parts of Firebase SDKs:

```
import { storage, db } from "./firebase";
```

But you can see that it doesn't import `firebase` itself.

You're going to have to find an import for `firebase`, maybe the same one you might have used in "./firebase".  It might look like this, as seen in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add-sdks-initialize):

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
```

Or something similar.

Comment: Thanks Doug, here is what I have in firebase.js


  import firebase from "firebase";

  const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp({
    TEXT REMOVED
  });

  const db =  firebaseApp.firestore();
  const auth = firebase.auth();
  const storage = firebase.storage();

  export { db, auth, storage };

Comment: OK, so it looks like your possible import line for `firebase` is in there.  Give it a try.